# Include "my sites" in the "all sites" list (iOS app)

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, communities-list

I have a small selection of sites listed in my summary view on the iOS app:

[image]

If you tap on "All Sites", and then filter to see "All Sites", I would expect to be able to scroll through/view *all* sites on the network.

[image]

However, my subset of pre-selected sites are not listed in under "All Sites". As an example, there's no Stack Overflow in the below view:

[image]

I don't really see the need to exclude the subset, so I'd suggest including it to stay faithful to the reference "All Sites".

iOS app: Version 1.6.1

Comment: In the android app, those are listed first, then all the rest. Sure you didn't miss them before scrolling?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, just checked again now. I'll update the post with the version details.

Comment: OK, so it's a fair request, surprised it's not there and nobody noticed before. Cheers! :)

Comment: They do show up if you search for them in the list though, which is a bit strange